# Develop an application that communicates with kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

I'm developing an application (user space) which is used to perform Linkedlist operation.

I want to develop a kernel module (A) which has the functions for linkedlist operations. and application (user space) gets some input values for processing and that values should be processed through the functions in kernelmodule(A) .

1. How to input values from the user space to kernel module.
2. How to send results from the kernel module (A) to my user space application ?
3. How to call functions and variables in the kernel module (A) from the Application.

My application can be c program?

Comment: yes [unwind](http://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind). i'm new to this. i can't ask help from my master. I need to finish the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a character driver interface to send values kernel space, use ioctl function to send user space data pointer to kernel space. In kernel space use copy_from_user() to copy user data to kernel space.

In case of linked list operations result can be either success or failure, which can be returned as return value of kernel ioctl function

For calling functions you can send the information to identify the function to be called as mentioned in first paragraph

Comment: hi [dragonyear](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1622292/dragonyear) pls create some very simple program to demonstrate this. I searched through net & i can't find. Pls help me out. i'm new to this.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that ioctl()s are not the only way (or even the best way) to do this. You could read/write to a device node or (and this is often the best and easiest way) use netlink sockets.